# What would be a good community promotion ad?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

One way we can promote this site is to create a community promotion ad to be shown on other SE sites. Each graduated SE site has a meta question where people can submit these ads ([math](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3278/community-promotion-ads-2012), [physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/980/community-promotion-ads-2012), [stats](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1030/community-promotion-ads-1h-2012)), and if they receive enough upvotes they will be automatically shown by the system.

If we are going to be advertising Mathematica.SE in this way, I think it would be useful to coordinate it so that we have one designated ad to represent the site, and then submit it to the community promotion ad questions on all related sites. So I'm posting this meta question to collect ideas. After a few days we can take the top voted submission and "distribute" it. (As a side effect, this could get people brainstorming about good logo ideas)

When an actual community ad is submitted, it is required to be in the form

```
[![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

   [1]: http://image-url
   [2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

The image must be exactly 220x250 pixels, in GIF or PNG format (not animated), and hosted on SE's Imgur account. I don't think it's strictly necessary for answers to *this* question to follow that format, but it would be convenient. Answers posted here should definitely include the three required elements: image, tagline, and URL.

---

### Note: the ads have now been posted!

They will be shown if they have at least 6 upvotes.  Please see here:

- [Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4305/12384)
- [Physics.SE](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1314/5874)
- [CrossValidated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1169/4764)
- [Theoretical CS](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1525/9511)
- [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1170) (added May 29)
- [TeX/LaTeX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2559/10783) (added June 21)

Comment: So if got it right, this is not about showing ads *on* Mma.SE, but about advertising Mma.SE on graduated related sites such as Math.SE, Physics.SE, StackOverflow.  We need to make an ad, and post it in those sites' ad-discussion.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. We don't get to show ads _on_ Mma.SE until (some time after) this site graduates.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky Okay, I see what you are trying to do. I missed that you were posting these in other meta threads. If they get voted up, they are perfectly appropriate. Carry on.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky we (finally) have a pretty good looking one [below](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/401/52). Thoughts?

Comment: I have also linked the new version (with new logo) [on my own site](http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/what_is_mma.html)

Answer (score 14):

This is just a tweak on Szabolcs' ad, with a different slogan to make the case for *why* someone should join (we're fun! Just look at some of the most upvoted questions!)

using `"BeachColors"`

[image: BeachColors scheme]

Also using `"BeachColors"` but reversing the ordering of the colours and removing the extremes:

[image: reversed BeachColors scheme]

```
colour5[s_: "SouthwestColors"] :=  Polygon[v_] /; 
 Length[v] == 4 :> {ColorData[s, 
  Rescale[(6 - 7 Norm[PolygonCentroid[v]])/4, {0, 1}, {0.2,  0.8}]], Polygon[v]}
```

Here's one with a bit more contrast, in response to Szabolcs's comment:

[image: reversed BeachColors scheme with contrast]

Now using the following, which takes the brown out:

```
colour5[s_: "SouthwestColors"] := Polygon[v_] /; 
  Length[v] == 4 :> {ColorData[s, 
  Rescale[(6 - 7 Norm[PolygonCentroid[v], 2])/4, {0, 1}, {0.1, 1}]], Polygon[v]}
```

---

We could do several versions with different colours. Consider:

```
colour5[s_: "SouthwestColors", {a_, b_}] /; 0 <= a <= 1 && 0 <= b <= 1 :=
   Polygon[v_] /; Length[v] == 4 :>
   {ColorData[s, Rescale[(6 - 7 Norm[PolygonCentroid[v], 2])/4, {0, 1}, {a, b}]],
    Polygon[v]}
```

And to explore:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[p /. triangulate /. moretriangles /. shrink /. shrink /. 
      colour3[] /. colour5[i, {min, max}] /. curve /. bolics], {i, 
  ColorData["Gradients"]}, {min, 0, 1}, {max, 0, 1}]
```

Here is `colour5["SunsetColors", {0.256, 0.844}]`:

[image: SunsetColors version]

Comment: Yes, I think we should use your slogan!  I like BeachColors too, though a bit more contrast in the second one would be nice

Comment: I split off the logo size and position in the code as separate variables to make them easier to tune (otherwise it takes some digging to find the right number to modify)

Comment: I think I like the last one. It just glows... :)

Comment: Now, if we could make them cdf scripts and have a shifting color scheme. :)

Comment: @rcollyer well, they do allow GIFs and GIFs can be animated ;-)  I don't think they'd be happy about an animated GIF though ...

Comment: It just needs a tag-line to conform to the community promotion ad standards (see the question).

Comment: @Szabolcs no they wouldn't. But, it was a thought!

Comment: @rcollyer You can see the tagline in my post, I just wrote: "Mathematica at StackExchange".  It's supposed to show up when hovering the ad (as a tooltip), but I can't see it in Firefox for some reason (neither in the posts, nor on the actual ads that appear on the site).  I think we can use the same tagline that she put on the image.

Comment: @Szabolcs I hadn't noticed that problem with FireFox, or, more correctly, I hadn't noticed it was a problem. But, I see the same behavior. And, you're right, either tagline will do.

Comment: @Szabolcs: I'm fine with posting the ad on meta.math.SE if we all come to an agreement, though as I said, I prefer Verbeia's last one to my initial proposal...

Comment: @J.M. I prefer that one too (I put a note at the beginning of my post).

Comment: @rcollyer Actually the tooltip *does* show up, but it only shows up on the actual ads, and only on the community promotion ads (not other ads).  The one I was lucky yo catch said "Alt Text" only ... not so nice ... I think we should have "Mathematica at StackExchange" as a tooltip.  It'll appear as soon as anyone hovers the ad, and it will make it clear where the link leads (in case there could have been some confusion).  When I hover the ads, two link appear at the bottom: one to comment on it and one pointing to [ad stats](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3278).

Comment: @Szabolcs I like your suggestion for a tool-tip. Also, I find it amusing that the Wolfram-Alpha ad says, "AltText," and the Khan Academy one says, "Tagline to show on mousover."

Comment: @rcollyer It's funny to see that the most popular ad (> 4 clicks per day) is the most cryptic one: Cantor's Attic.  Maybe we can learn from it: it's not always advantageous to make it completely obvious what is being advertised.

Comment: @Szabolcs that was why I clicked on it before. :)

Comment: I like this :-) If people are in agreement I can go ahead and put the last one on Physics meta (although I wouldn't mind of someone else does so, because that way I'd get to vote for it).

Comment: These are great, I love them all! The last one is particularly reminiscent of *Mathematica* 6's spikey, and the second one is a bit like *Mathematica* 5's. They all clearly say "*Mathematica*", but without cribbing too much from the official symbols. Perfect!

Comment: @J.M. I think it's okay to [go ahead and post the ad now](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3278/community-promotion-ads-2012). EVeryone seems to like it.  We can always change it later to a better version if someone makes one, or rotate through several versions (whuber's idea).

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky I think it's okay to [go ahead and post the ad now](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/980/community-promotion-ads-2012). EVeryone seems to like it.  We can always change it later to a better version if someone makes one, or rotate through several versions (whuber's idea).

Comment: OK, done. http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/1314/124

Comment: @Szabolcs: [It is finished.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4305)

Answer (score 7):

**NOTE:**  I'm leaving this post here because it has the code, but I myself prefer [@Verbeia's last version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NddzD.png).

---

### The ad!

Pieced together from [existing bits](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/395/12), here's one possibility.  This is a start.

[image: Mathematica at StackExchange]

**Please upvote if you think it's ready to be used.** Please do comment if you think something needs to be changed first (I'll update the post with the changes).  Or even better: make the changes and post another variation.  (Note that everything I used here is borrowed from other posts.)

The usual "Help this community grow" line (that's used by SE in their in-house ads) can seem a little boring, but I think it immediately makes it clear that this is not an advertisement for Mathematica the program, but for a Mathematica QA site.

---

### Posting the ad on graduated SE sites

<strike>I am going to post it on [Physics.SE](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/980/community-promotion-ads-2012), [Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3278/community-promotion-ads-2012) and [CrossValidated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1030/community-promotion-ads-1h-2012) if it gets enough upvotes here (say, clearly more than the parent question).</strike>  **Instead** I propose that the people who post the upvoted ads should be high rep users on the respective sites, so the ads are received better. @J.M. has high rep on Math.SE, @DavidZaslavsky is a mod on Physics and @whuber is a mod on CrossValidated.  Are you willing to post these yourself, when the ads are ready (please reply in comments)?  Finally what do you think about advertising on [Theoretical CS](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1448/community-promotion-ads-2012) as well?

---

### Full code

Full code follows (copy, paste and evaluate). I chose to make it fully in Mathematica so everyone on this site can easily contribute and can easily change things.  Upscaling and doing an `ImageResize` ensures that everything has a uniform, platform-independent smooth look and that the polygons in the logo are joined without white "cracks" inbetween them.  Note that for now I used the font [Candara](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candara) which might not be present on your system (if you have Windows or Office ([even on Mac](http://macintoshhowto.com/advanced/how-to-get-the-windows-vista-fonts-for-free-on-your-macintosh.html)), it's very likely you have it already).

```
p = Polygon[
   Table[N[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}], {t, \[Pi]/10, 2 \[Pi], (2 \[Pi])/5}]];

triangulate = 
  Polygon[v_] :> (Polygon[Append[#, Mean[v]]] & /@ 
     Partition[v, 2, 1, {1, 1}]);

moretriangles = 
  Polygon[{a_, b_, c_}] :> 
   With[{ab = (a + b)/2, bc = (b + c)/2, 
     ca = (c + a)/2}, {Polygon[{a, ab, ca}], Polygon[{ab, b, bc}], 
     Polygon[{c, ca, ab}], Polygon[{c, ab, bc}]}];

shrink = Polygon[{a_, b_, c_}] :> 
   With[{aa = (6 a + b + c)/8, bb = (a + 6 b + c)/8, 
     cc = (a + b + 6 c)/8}, {Polygon[{a, b, bb, aa}], 
     Polygon[{b, c, cc, bb}], Polygon[{c, a, aa, cc}], 
     Polygon[{aa, bb, cc}]}];

curve = Polygon[v_] :> 
   FilledCurve[
    Line[Map[{10 - #, #}/10 &, Range[0, 10]].#] & /@ 
     Partition[v, 2, 1, {1, 1}]];

f[r_] := Re[(ArcSin[2 r - 1] + \[Pi]/2)/2];

bolics = v : {_?NumberQ, _} :> f[Norm[v]] v;

colour3[s_: LightGray] := q : Polygon[{_, _, _}] :> {s, q}

PolygonCentroid[pts_?MatrixQ] := 
 With[{dif = Map[Det, Partition[pts, 2, 1, {1, 1}]]}, 
  ListConvolve[{{1, 1}}, Transpose[pts], {-1, -1}].dif/(3 Total[dif])]

colour4[s_: "SouthwestColors"] := 
 Polygon[v_] /; 
   Length[v] == 4 :> {ColorData[
    s, (7 Norm[PolygonCentroid[v], 2] - 2)/4], Polygon[v]}

logo = Graphics[
  p /. triangulate /. moretriangles /. shrink /. shrink /. 
      colour3[] /. colour4[] /. curve /. bolics]

logosize = 5;
logoposition = 11.5;

ad = Show[logo, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> False, 
   PlotRange -> 1/logosize {{-11, 11}, {0, 25} - logoposition}, 
   Epilog -> {Text[Style["\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"Mathematica\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\).SE", 
       FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> Scaled[1/10], 
       FontFamily -> "Candara"], Scaled[{0.5, 0.09}]],
     Text[
      Style["Help this community grow!", 
       FontSize -> Scaled[1/(10 Sqrt[2])], FontFamily -> "Candara", 
       FontColor -> Gray], Scaled[{0.5, 0.89}]]}];


adimg = ImageResize[
  Rasterize[ad, "Image", ImageResolution -> 3 72], {220, 250}]
```

Comment: As an active CV user (and one who has frequently used MMA in replies there) I would be delighted to post the winning ad there.  Or even rotate through the ads: every one of the contributions in this thread looks great to me :-).  PS You might have enough rep here to ping anyone you like in chat using the "@@" construct--could be worth a try in the future.

Comment: @whuber I think rotating the ads is a great idea!  I tried @@-ing you in the Mathematica chatroom a few hours ago, but you didn't respond: I think you didn't receive the notification.  I think @@ is a moderator-only tool.

Comment: @Szabolcs It is a moderator only feature

Comment: @Sz Yes, sorry about that--I didn't hear any pings. I thought it would be worth a try, since most moderator tools are available to people with your high reputation.

Comment: @Sz Is [this](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/1166) what you had in mind?

Comment: @whuber Yes, exactly!

Comment: It needs one more vote to get over the vote threshold - thanks @whuber!

Comment: @V Alas, to be acted on it needs to be posted in a *successor* thread: I mistakenly posted it in the thread for 2H 2011 rather than 1H 2012. So I had to migrate the ad and now voting needs to start all over again.  Please visit http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/1169 if you would like to vote.

Answer (score 5):

As you said, if we are going to promote the site, we might need a **preliminary logo**.

I didn't post about this yet (I thought it was too soon---we just got out of private beta!), but my idea for a site logo was using a [**spikey**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Spikey.html):

[image]

We can have a spikey-design contest to create a special logo for this site only.  Who can make the best looking one in Mathematica?

**Why a custom spikey?**

- It is instantly recognizable as something related to Mathematica
- Yet it will not be identical to any official Mathematica logo, so it will not be version specific and will not step on any trademarks

We have several people here who like to create art with Mathematica.  I think there'll be a lot of interest!

The code for generating the version 4 logo is [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/114/), for version 5 it's [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/5700/), and a Wolfram Blog entry about spikey making is [here](http://blog.wolfram.com/?year=2007&monthnum=05&name=making-the-mathematica-6-spikey).

Comment: I would suggest we pick a colour that has not been used for an official spikey. Say green or a bluish purple. Or, as an alternative to a spikey, some other icosahedron based graphic. See my [web site](http://www.verbeia.com/) for a non-spikey alternative.

Comment: @Verbeia I agree, I was thinking about something as different as possible, while still preserving some vague resemblance to Mathematica.  The image on your site also reminds of Mathematica a bit, even though it is completely different.

Comment: Excellent idea. The logo search might deserve its own separate question though...

Comment: @David Yes, it should be a separate question.  But from chat I got the impression most would like a different kind of logo, so let's wait with that.  I just wanted to throw in the idea

Comment: Designing a log should *really* become part of a post that starts suggesting designs for this site, as outlined here: **[The 7 Essential Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/)**