# Mitigating the damage from the new site theme

Tags: discussion, feature-request

The [new site theme rollout](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2374/38205) may not be everyone's cup of tea. It's certainly not mine.

What strategies are there for getting a cleaner site layout which focuses on what we care about?

Answer (score 8):

#### Update

This now fixes the issue with the syntax highlighting colors being wrong, too

#### Original

Here are screenshots of what this will do for you:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Basically I just tried to make it so what we care about (questions and answers) are what the site displays most prominently. I also got our old logo back, until that resource is destroyed at least.

#### How to Get

At Carl Lange's suggestion I installed the [Stylus browser extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne?hl=en) for Chrome.

Once you have that, you just make a new style and you can import this CSS (there's an Import button):

```
@-moz-document regexp("https://mathematica\\..*stackexchange.com/.*") {
.pln{color:#326ab3}@media screen{.str{color:#833}.mma_msg{color:#833;font-style:italic}.mma_use{color:#833;font-weight:bold}.mma_iot{color:#555;font-weight:bold}.atn{color:#326ab3;font-weight:bold}.com{color:#555}.kwd{color:#000}.atv{color:#060;font-style:italic}.atn{color:#326ab3;font-weight:bold}.tag{color:#000;font-weight:bold}.lit{color:#833}.pln{color:#326ab3}.pun{color:#000}}@media print,projection{.str,.use,.msg{color:#833}.com{color:#555}.kwd{color:#000;font-weight:bold}.atv{color:#060;font-style:italic}.tag{color:#000;font-weight:bold}.lit{color:#833}.mma_use{color:#833;font-weight:bold}.mma_msg{color:#833;font-style:italic}.mma_iot{color:#555;font-weight:bold}.atn{color:#326ab3;font-weight:bold}.pun{color:#000}}pre.prettyprint{background:#EEE;padding:20px}ol.linenums{margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0}li.L0,li.L1,li.L2,li.L3,li.L5,li.L6,li.L7,li.L8{list-style-type:none}li.L1,li.L3,li.L5,li.L7,li.L9{background:#eee}

#left-sidebar{
    display: none
}

#mainbar {
    padding: 0px 25px;
    width: 100%;
}

#content {
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
    display: none;
}

#hot-network-questions {
    display: none;
}

.community-bulletin, #newsletter-ad, .ad-container {
    display: none
}

}

@-moz-document regexp("https://mathematica\\..*stackexchange\\.com/questions/.*") {

#mainbar {
    padding: 0px 25px 0px 0px;
    width: calc(100% - 275px);
}

#sidebar {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
}
}

@-moz-document regexp("https://mathematica\\..*stackexchange\\.com/questions/ask") {
#mainbar {
    padding: 0px 25px 0px 25px;
    width: 100%
}

#mainbar.ask-mainbar {
    width: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
    display: none;
}
}

@-moz-document url-prefix("https://mathematica.stackexchange.com") {
.tabs-filter {
    display: none;
}

img.h-auto.wmx100 {
    width:0px; 
    height:0px; 
    margin: 15px 15px 15px 0px;
    padding: 30px 0px 30px 350px;
    background: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/mathematica/img/logo@2.png?v=37ecb83d823e);
    background-size: cover;
}
}
```

#### All SE

Here's a theme that will apply across all StackExchange sites:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix("https://mathematica.stackexchange.com") {
.pln{color:#326ab3}@media screen{.str{color:#833}.mma_msg{color:#833;font-style:italic}.mma_use{color:#833;font-weight:bold}.mma_iot{color:#555;font-weight:bold}.atn{color:#326ab3;font-weight:bold}.com{color:#555}.kwd{color:#000}.atv{color:#060;font-style:italic}.atn{color:#326ab3;font-weight:bold}.tag{color:#000;font-weight:bold}.lit{color:#833}.pln{color:#326ab3}.pun{color:#000}}@media print,projection{.str,.use,.msg{color:#833}.com{color:#555}.kwd{color:#000;font-weight:bold}.atv{color:#060;font-style:italic}.tag{color:#000;font-weight:bold}.lit{color:#833}.mma_use{color:#833;font-weight:bold}.mma_msg{color:#833;font-style:italic}.mma_iot{color:#555;font-weight:bold}.atn{color:#326ab3;font-weight:bold}.pun{color:#000}}pre.prettyprint{background:#EEE;padding:20px}ol.linenums{margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0}li.L0,li.L1,li.L2,li.L3,li.L5,li.L6,li.L7,li.L8{list-style-type:none}li.L1,li.L3,li.L5,li.L7,li.L9{background:#eee}

img.h-auto.wmx100 {
    
    width:0px; 
    height:0px; 
    margin: 15px 15px 15px 0px;
    padding: 30px 0px 30px 350px;
    background: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/mathematica/img/logo@2.png?v=37ecb83d823e);
    background-size: cover;
}
}

@-moz-document domain("stackexchange.com") {
.unified-theme {
    padding-top: 0px;
}

.top-bar._fixed {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

#left-sidebar{
    display: none;
}

#mainbar {
    padding: 0px 25px;
    width: 100%;
}

#content {
    border: none;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
    display: none;
}

#hot-network-questions {
    display: none;
}

.community-bulletin, #newsletter-ad, .ad-container {
    display: none
}

.tabs-filter {
    display: none;
}

}

@-moz-document regexp("https://.*stackexchange\\.com/questions/.*") {
#mainbar {
    padding: 0px 25px 0px 0px;
    width: calc(100% - 304px);
    margin: 0px;
}

#sidebar {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    width: 280px;
}

.tabs-filter {
    display: initial;
}
}

@-moz-document regexp("https://chat.stackexchange.com/.*") {
#mainbar {
    padding: 0px 25px 0px 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
    display: block;
    width: 28%;
}

.tabs-filter {
    display: initial;
}
}

@-moz-document regexp("https://.*stackexchange\\.com/questions/ask") {
#mainbar {
    padding: 0px 25px 0px 25px;
    width: 100%
}

#mainbar.ask-mainbar {
    width: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
    display: none;
}
}
```